# How to estimate a multiple regression function that has interactions between the independent variables and is potentially non-linear?

Tags: regression, modeling

I understand how linear regression is used on a sample to produce a model of how each independent variable affects the dependent variable. What I would like to do is something similar, except where the model can also represent interactions between the independent variables. Also, I would like the model to be nonlinear if possible. With preference given to simpler solutions, what is the range of available solutions to such a problem?

**EDIT**

To be more specific, the following are the details of my problem. I'm developing a neural network algorithm that has 11 continuous covariates that control it's behavior. These include size of different layers, learning rate, and a number of other things. I'm trying to understand how different values for the covariates produce different performance levels and why. Intuition and preliminary analysis (based on Monte Carlo sampling) tell me that there are interactions among some covariates and that effects are not likely to be linear in all cases. However, it's not obvious to me what the type of the relationships are (e.g. polynomial, exponential, etc.). Also, for efficiency, as I add more covariates and apply the algorithm to different contexts, I would like to have a method of regression in place that doesn't assume linearity and isn't dependent on foreknowledge of the type of relationship between the covariates and the performance (dependent variable).

Comment: @Macro only one

Comment: @whuber Do the details I added seem helpful?

Comment: Yes (+1).  I removed earlier comments that are now moot in light of the edit.  The additional information is revealing: for instance, it confirms my original suspicion that you're not dealing with the simple quadratic nonlinearities often assumed by statisticians whenever they see the word "interaction": yours can be as complex and mysterious as the workings of the NN itself.

Comment: @whuber interesting, but does that bode poorly for finding a solution?

Comment: Matt, I am no expert, but I understand that NNs can work in difficult-to-characterize ways. If indeed an NN succeeds better than a regression model, doesn't that (strongly) suggest that regression methods to analyze the NN will be less than satisfactory? I don't mean to be discouraging, because possibly analysis of your NN can provide revelation, but we might as well be realistic about what can be achieved. To begin with, consider using robust, exploratory, highly non-parametric techniques rather than trying to build formal regression models. Aim for discovery rather than confirmation.

Comment: Neural networks are used for classification and regression is used for prediction.  So it does seem odd to try to use regression to explain the neural network.

Comment: Matt, A closer reading of the edit suggests I may be off base here: it sounds like you're not trying to peer into the NNs themselves, or replicate them through a statistical model, but only to understand how certain tuning parameters might relate to performance metrics. It would be good to be aware of Michael Chernick's distinction between nonlinear relationships between inputs and outputs and nonlinear models themselves. Even so, I still think the problem is best approached in an exploratory spirit before proceeding to more formal modeling.

Comment: @whuber Yes, examining how tuning relates to performance metrics is my aim. What do you have in mind by "robust, exploratory, highly non-parametric techniques"? I'm not really expecting regression to give me an exactly-correct model of how the tuning affects the NN. Rather, I'm just hoping for something to point me in the right direction about how the NN functions internally.

Comment: @MattMunson There are many different types of Neural Networks, which internally use different algorithms to reduce some form of error metric. Can you say any more about the structure and algorithms that the NN in question is implementing. This might be very relevant in giving insight into how it behaves and the effect that its parameters may have on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part about interaction terms in the linear model is easy to answer .  If you have variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ that you think interact in the model add the term $X_1$ multiplied by $X_2$ and test to see if the coefficient is significantly different from 0.  That term is your interaction term. Regarding a nonlinear model, why do you think you need a model that is nonlinear in the parameters.  There are many options for nonlinear models and the choice should be dictated by how the regression parameters are connected to the covariate in a nonlinear fashion. Should the coefficients be exponents for the covariates (for example)?

Comment: Michael, the term 'multivariate' in the title makes me thinks this refers to a regression model where the outcome in multivariate (since 'multiple' usually refers to the case of more than one predictor). In that case, the interaction coefficient becomes a vector and is less straightforward than what you wrote here. Some clarification is required from the OP about whether he/she really meant "multivariate".

Comment: @Macro I didn't think much about the use of the term multivariate in the OPs description of the problem.  Note that he mentions linear regression, independent variables but only one dependent variable.  I think he is think of multiple regression rather than mutlivariate regression and just simply wants to know how interaction effects get introduced in the model.  Let's see if he replies.

Comment: @Michael There is only one dependent variable. Regarding nonlinearity, without going into the details, I am in situation where I suspect the presence of, and am not confident that I can rule out, nonlinearity. Worse though, I cannot really derive what the nature of the nonlinear relationship would be, if it is indeed nonlinear (eg. polynomial, exponential, etc.). I posted some further details above.

Comment: My answer is then correct for linear regression.  But your terminology may still be confusing us because it sounds like you are referring to the covariates when you are using the term parameters.  The variables that you think might be interacting we statisticians call covariates (or independent variables, or explanatory variables or regressors).  The model coefficients are what we refer to as parameters.  Linear regression require that the model be linear in the parameters and not necessarily the covariates.

Comment: If you are concerned about nonlinearity in the covariates that does not move you into the realm of nonlinear regression.  That would only be the case if you have nonlinearity in the parameters such as if you think the covariate X enters the model as a power where the power is the parameter yuo need to estimate from your data.

Comment: @Michael Yes, you are right about my misunderstanding of the terminology. It is indeed the parameters, as you define them, that I suspect are nonlinear. I will edit my question to clear up the confusion.

Comment: You can then use linear regression but would need to specifyhow the covariates enter the model (e.g. log X X$^3$ etc.)

Comment: @Michael what if I don't know a priori which is appropriate? Would I just try every possible combination and then pick the one with the best fit?

Comment: You don't want to just create a large number of potential models fit them all and pick the best fit.  Find a small number of models that you think are plausible and see which ones fit well. I still don't understand how the regression model will help with the Neural Network classifier.

Comment: @Michael I am exploring novel NN algorithms with many different tuning variables. I have some ideas about how the algorithm works and how to improve it, but much of the algorithm's internal dynamics are a mystery to me, and I expect pitfalls and limitations of unanticipated nature. My hope is that, if I can model how the tuning variables relate to performance, then I can gain insight into why the algorithm behaves as it does, and thus ideas for improving it.

Comment: @Michael In regards to creating a large number of potential models: is this bad because it can involve much computation and labor, or because it is statistically invalid?

Comment: The problem is statistical.  There is the issue of multiplicity.  If you search hard enough for significant results you are bound to find them.  There is a p-value adjustment that should be made for running several tests.  The penalty will be large when you do a very large numbe rof test and it will be difficult to judge anything as significant.

Comment: @Michael Ok, thanks a lot for your help Michael. I just have two more questions. 1)Can I avoid the issue of multiplicity if I search hard with one sample, and then test only the best model on a second sample? 2) Do you know of any algorithms that do a search of nonlinear algorithms, or would I have to code this from scratch?

Comment: I don't think you can nor should you avoid the multiplicity problem.  it is okay to try out and compare a few models.  With a small number of models you do not pay a large penalty.  I do not know of any algorithms and do not see how one could creat algorithms to search through nonlinear models.  I think the best approach is to pick out a few that seem sensible. I think here you mean linear models that involve nonlinear functions of the covariates along with some interaction terms.